# Layer navigation menu

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 tables, top_category, bottom_category, products, at the moment i have listed the top_category, i am confused about how to approach listing the second category but have it list   so it knows what top_category it belongs too, this is why i have the foreign keys  parent, so if the top_category for example is:

```
prod1 
prod2
prod3
etc
```

and now i want to load my bottom category into these top_categories like this:

```
prod1
 -subprod1
 -subprod2
 -subprod3
prod2
 -subprod4
 -subprod5
prod3
 -subprod6
etc
```

This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE top_category (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) 
);

CREATE TABLE bottom_category (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) ,
  top_category_id INT REFERENCES top_category
);

create table product (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(100) ,
  bottom_category_id int references bottom_category
);
```

This is my php & html code:

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php'); 

try
    { 
        $result = $pdo->query(" SELECT * FROM top_category ORDER BY top_name ASC; ");
    } // end try
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    { 
        echo 'There was a error fetching the products.' . $e->getMessage();
        exit(); 
    } // end catch

$products = array();

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $products[] = array('id' => $row['id'],    
                        'top_name' => $row['top_name']);
}

?>

<div class="sidebar">
    <h4 class="sidebar-header">Select Products</h4>
    <form class="nav-search-form">
        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search products">
    </form>
    <nav class="sidebar-links"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a id="red" href="index.php">New Products</a></li>
            <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['top_name']);?></a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div><!-- sidebar -->
<div class="main-content">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should combine your `top_category` and `bottom_category` tables into a single table, perhaps `category`.  There's really no reason that these need to be separated.  It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) 
);
```

For all "top" categories, the `parent_id` would be 0.  For any "bottom" categories, the `parent_id` would be the `id` of the "top" category under which it falls.  In addition to cleaning up the database a bit, it allows for future expansion into more than just two layers if you desired.

Then you'd create a recursive function (a function that calls itself) to loop through and display the menu structure, something like this:

```
function menus( $parent_id, $pdo ) {
    $menu_query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = :parent_id";
    $menu_result = $pdo->prepare( $menu_query );
    $menu_result->execute( array( ":parent_id" => $parent_id ));

    $menu = "";
    if( $menu_result->rowCount() ) {
        $menu .= "<ul>\n";

        while( $menu_row = $menu_result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
            $menu .= "<li>{$menu_row['NAME']}\n";
            $menu .= menus( $menu_row['id'], $pdo );
            $menu .= "</li>\n";
        }

        $menu .= "</ul>\n";
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Then to display your menu, you'd simply print the results of the function:

```
print menus( 0, $pdo );
```

It'll return a structure that basically looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>prod1
    <ul>
      <li>subprod1</li>
      <li>subprod2</li>
      <li>subprod3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>prod2
    <ul>
      <li>subprod4</li>
      <li>subprod5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>prod3
    <ul>
      <li>subprod6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(Indentation added for readability, the code above does not add the indentation, but that's the structure).

Here's essentially what this does.  The function pulls all of the top-level entries, then as it loops through each one, it calls itself but with the ID of the currently-selected entry, which then pulls all of the children, and does the same thing.  Each time it completes a layer (i.e. creates the structure for all entries at a given level), it returns that to the parent function and concatenates the data.

I haven't tested this specific code, so it may contain a minor issue here or there, but the concept is solid (I've implemented it many times myself).

**UPDATE (styling)**

If you want to apply styles to this menu where each layer has a different set of styles, there are two ways to do this.  The first is to a $level variable to the function so that it'd be defined like this:

```
function menus( $parent_id, $pdo, $level )
```

Start out by calling it with `0` for the level, then within the function call it with `$level + 1`.  This way, each successive level will be called with the correct value.  You can create classes based on this, such as `level-1`, then define the element as having `class="level-{$level}"`.

The second is to wrap the entire thing in a `<div>`, and then use immediate child selectors to reference a specific level.  `div>ul>li` would be the first level of `<li>`, `div>ul>li>ul>li` would be the second level of `<li>`, and so on.

Comment: I am getting a few errors, Undefined variable: pdo, and Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in... sidebar.php and missing argument 2 for menus()... i had more errors but i fixed them. these ones i am unable to work out.

Comment: `$pdo` represents your PDO object for your DB connection. Change it to whatever you're using. The error `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare()` will be fixed bu this as well. I edited the code to fix `missing argument 2 for menus()`.

Comment: yep sorry i forgot to reply that i worked out those 2 errors, and it all works now except that i am getting a repeating message saying NOTICE: undefined variable menu in my sidebar, and eventually down the page it outputs what i want it too, so its working, its just outputting a error prior to it working.

Comment: The NOTICE is my fault. I've added `$menu = "";` on line 5 of the function to fix the issue because it was undefined.

Comment: yeah i worked that one out too, thanks heaps btw, i did notice that i added anchor tags to the while loop is that the correct way to add the links? also its creating 2 blank anchor tags before it generates the list.

Comment: I would put the links inside of the `<li>` tags. If you're doing that, I don't know why it'd be creating blank ones, unless there are blank rows being pulled from you table.

Comment: yeah working, is there a way to add classes or id's to these nested lists or links in this while loop, because its nesting so many times, and i only want to style certain lists, how can i do this? if i add a class or id to the ul, or li, or the a, it does it to every single one in the loop. Basically how would you go about style/layout in this situation, what is the best solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give some tips on styling each level.

Comment: Hey i know this is an old post i have posted previously, but i like the way you did the dynamic navigation structure, so i was wondering how you take that next step and making each last child of a parent category open a list of products that belong to that child? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're wanting to do, and I don't know if we could fully expand on that in the comments. Would it be possible for you to post a new question showing what you currently have and describing in more detail what you're wanting to accomplish? Once you've posted the question, you can private message or email me with the link so I can find it. Be sure to reference this question in your new question so that others that might also provide input will have the proper context.